# How to perform a rolling diff?

Tags: c#, diff, patch

How do you perform a rolling diff between 2 files to determine only the portion of files that have changed?

Comment: I've never heard the term "rolling" diff.  Could you be more specific?

Comment: my bad i mean a 'rolling checksum'. When that rolling checksum is different between 2 files, then there is a difference and you can then only copy over the changed portions of a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rsync is an example of what you're looking for. There's even a tech report about it: http://www.samba.org/rsync/tech_report/tech_report.html